# How to sort dataframe based on number of commas in variable

Tags: r, string, sorting

I have a dataframe containing a list of comma-separated strings.

```
x <- c("a,b","a,b,c,d","a","a,b,c)
y <- data.frame(x)
```

The data frame should be sorted / ordered according to the number of commas occurring in each row.

To do this, I tried to extract the number of commas to a new variable in order to sort the dataframe:

```
library(stringr)    
y$new <- str_extract_all(y$x, ",")
```

First problem: The variable shows lists instead of strings. Second problem: Row without comma shows as character(0).

```
    x       new
1   a,b     ,
2   a,b,c,d c(",", ",", ",")
3   a       character(0)
4   a,b,c   c(",",",")
```

If I could get the result as a string, I could possibly order it like:

```
y[order(y$new),]
```

Expected result would be:

```
    x       new
1   a       n/a
2   a,b     ,
3   a,b,c   ,,
4   a,b,c,d ,,,
```

Main thing is that the data frame is sorted, and there might be an easier was than extracting the commas.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `stringr::str_count` to count the number of commas and use it in `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
y %>%  arrange(stringr::str_count(x, ","))

#        x
#1       a
#2     a,b
#3   a,b,c
#4 a,b,c,d
```

Using base R that would be

```
y[order(lengths(regmatches(x, gregexpr(",", y$x)))), , drop = FALSE]
```

Or as @Roland suggests another options is to remove everything except `","` and then `order` based on number of characters.

```
y[order(nchar(gsub("[^,]", "", y$x))), , drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: I'd use `gsub`like this: `y[order(nchar(gsub("[^,]", "", x))),, drop = FALSE]`